# Morphism between $\mathcal{O}_X$ - modules is locally an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, quasicoherent-sheaves

Given two quasi - coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$ - modules $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ on a scheme $X$ and a morphism $f:\mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ and a point $x\in X$ such that $f_x:\mathcal{F}_x\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_x$ is an isomorphism, I wish to prove the following:

If $\mathcal{F}$ is locally of finite type and $\mathcal{G}$ is locally of finite presentation, then there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f|_U:\mathcal{F}|_U\rightarrow \mathcal{G}|_U$ is an isomorphism.

I think I am close to solving it myself, but I am missing a crucial step in my argument.

Assume $X = \rm{Spec}(A)$ is affine. Then $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are associated to $A$ - modules $M$ and $N$ of finite type and finite presentation respectively. I want to show that $\rm{ker}(f)$ and $\rm{coker}(f)$ are locally of finite type. Because both $\rm{ker}(f)$ and $\rm{coker}(f)$ are quasi - coherent and thus it follows from $\rm{ker}(f)_x = 0 = \rm{coker}(f)_x$ that there is an open nbdh $U$ of $x$ such that $\rm{ker}(f)|_U = \rm{coker}(f)|_U = 0$ (this has been shown before).

But I don't know how to show that $\rm{ker}(f)$ and $\rm{coker}(f)$ are locally of finite type. Is that even true? And is my idea basically correct?

Thank you very much for any comment!

Comment: So that coker(f) is finite is almost by definition, because M being finite and N being finitely presented imply that we have N_2 \to N_1 \to N \to 0 and M_1 \to M \to 0 with M_i, N_i finite free, then N_2 \oplus M_1 \to N_1 \to coker(f) \to 0 gives the desired resolution. For ker(f) note that since ker(f) injects into M and M_1 surjects onto M, the kernel of the map from M_1 \onto N surjects onto the kernel of f, so we can assume that M is finite free, and N is finitely presented, and we want to show that the kernel of a morphism between them is finite.

Comment: I see that $\rm{coker}(f)$ is of finite type easily. As I understand your argument, you reduce to the situation of an epimorphism $R^n\rightarrow N$ and show that its kernel is of finite type. This is already known to me. But since $f$ is not surjective, why should $M_1 \rightarrow N$ be surjective?

Comment: Hi Teddyboer, sorry I got distracted and didn't finish arguing for you: so using our previous notation and letting $\pi: N_1 \to N$ denote the surjection from before we can replace $M$ with $M_1 \oplus N_1$ and leave $N$ alone, so letting $L$ denote the kernel of the natural map from $M_1 \to N$ we get the short exact sequence $0 \to L \oplus \text{ker}(\pi) \to M_1 \oplus N_1 \to N \to 0$. Because $L$ surjects onto the kernel of f and $L \oplus \text{ker}(\pi)$ surjects onto $L$ it suffices to show the kernel of this map is finite. But then we reduce to the case above.

Comment: So now suppose $N$ is a finitely presented module and $R^m$ surjects onto $N$ with kernel $K$, we want to show that $K$ is finite. We know we have $0 \to X \to R^n \to N$ with $X$ finite, so using the projectivity of free modules we get a commutative rectangle with $\iota: X \to K, N=N$, and $\rho: R^n \to R^m$, using the snake lemma we see that $0 \to \text{im}(\iota) \to  K \to \text{Coker}(\rho) \to 0$ and thus $K$ is finitely generated, because it is stuck between two finitely generated modules.